# ¿Cómo convertir un array de hashes en un hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo un array que contiene dentro n hashes en la siguiente forma y del cual estoy obteniendo sus últimos 4 elementos.

array_hashes.last(4), lo que me retorna:

```
[{:id=>1, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 13 Apr 2020, :value=>0.14, :avg_value=>0 :type=>"week"}, {:id=>2, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 20 Apr 2020, :value=>0.04, :avg_value=>0, :type=>"week"}, {:id=>3, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 27 Apr 2020, :value=>0.37, :avg_value=>0, :type=>"week"}, {:project_id=>4, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 04 May 2020, :value=>0.04, :avg_value=>0, :type=>"week"}]
```

Sin embargo necesito obtener:

```
{:id=>1, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 13 Apr 2020, :value=>0.14, :avg_value=>0 :type=>"week"}, {:id=>2, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 20 Apr 2020, :value=>0.04, :avg_value=>0, :type=>"week"}, {:id=>3, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 27 Apr 2020, :value=>0.37, :avg_value=>0, :type=>"week"}, {:project_id=>4, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 04 May 2020, :value=>0.04, :avg_value=>0, :type=>"week"}
```

Para lo cuál, en la documentación de ruby he buscado diferentes formas de hacerlo, una es usando .inject(:merge), pero al usarlo retorna el último elemento del array como hash, y no los 4 elementos que necesito, estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
array_hashes.last(4).inject(:merge)
```

Y obtengo:

```
{:project_id=>4, :username=>nil, :week=>Mon, 04 May 2020, :value=>0.04, :avg_value=>0, :type=>"week"}
```

Entiendo que inject(:merge) funciona con la forma {"k"=>"v"}, por lo que a mi array es {:símbolo=>value}, probé usar stringify_keys pero tampoco tuve resultados.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar por favor diciendome qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias!

Comment: Es que lo que necesitas obtener no es una estructura existente en ruby, son solo 4 hashes separados por una coma, coma que es de un array, array que no quieres. ¿puedes explicar en tu pregunta qué es lo que quieres conseguir con estos 4 valores? ¿de qué manera piensas usarlos? ¿acaso quieres convertir los 4 hashes del array en uno solo? y si es así ¿qué valores predominarían en ese único hash?

Comment: Originalmente lo que obtengo son n hashes separados por coma, que he puesto dentro de un array para obtener los últimos 4 elementos de ese array. No sé como podría obtener los 4 hashes de otra forma, ya que necesito el hash completo para pasarselo al controlador que renderizará un json al front end.

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema que los hashes estén en un array?. En un json válido tampoco puedes poner 4 objetos sueltos, lo normal es que vayan todos dentro de un array. De esos 4 hashes, ¿piensas ponerlos todos dentro de una misma respuesta json? ¿como deberían ir? Ten en mente que [un array de objects es un json válido](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIVp7.png) y [objects simplemente separados por coma no lo es](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ETg.png).

Comment: Finalmente después de mucho luchar, usé el objeto tal como era retornado y lo recorrí. No había tomado en consideración que otra parte del código estaba retornando el mismo objeto y por eso no lograba obtener los datos correctamente. El array de hashes como mencionaste funcionaba perfecto para retornarlo al controlador. Mi falta de experiencia me jugó una mala pasada, muchas gracias @AlterLagos

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = a.reduce { |new_hash, item| new_hash.merge(item) }
```

lo que hace este método es hacer un recorrido de los items del array, los mergea y devuelve el valor formando un nuevo hash.